# Delete duplicate lines from string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to remove all duplicate lines from a string. For example i have a string

```
Mystring = "INSERT INTO Table(Column1, Column2) Values(50, 50), (100, 100), (50, 50)"
```

How to delete second (50, 50)

Comment: This looks like you're dealing with an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The first questions springing to mind are, how did that data get into the string in the first place (can it be filtered there?) or can you not write the sql in a way to deal with duplicate data, rather than trying to string mangle the sql statement itself?

Comment: There seems to be only one line in that string.

Comment: Um, that `String` only contains one line. If you can't even communicate your problem clearly then it's going to be hard for us to provide any useful solution. Please describe your problem CLEARLY, which means that we need the rules that the code must implement, not just a single example of what the code might do. Also, your question is off-topic anyway because questions of the form "I want to do X, tell me how" aren't valid here. If you haven't made an attempt to implement a solution then it's too soon to be posting here.